# How to remove JavaScript code in the template header (Joomla! 3.0.x)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, joomla, mootools

I have created a template in Joomla! 3x, but I want to remove the default JavaScript code and stylesheets in the page header.

My code is:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

//Remove default configuration
$doc->setGenerator("");
$headData = $doc -> getHeadData();
unset($headData['metaTags']['http-equiv']);
$doc -> setHeadData($headData);   //Is OK
$doc -> _styleSheets = array();   //Is OK
$doc -> _scripts = array();       //Is OK
$doc -> _script =  array();  **// Not OK**

//Add foundation
$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/'.$this->template.'/css/foundation.css');
$doc->addScript('templates/'.$this->template.'/js/jquery.js');
$doc->addScript('templates/'.$this->template.'/js/modernizr.foundation.js');
```

The template header HTML is now:

```
function keepAlive() { var myAjax = new Request({method: "get", url: "index.php"}).send();} window.addEvent("domready", function(){ keepAlive.periodical(840000); });
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.hasTooltip').tooltip({});
});
// The block is not removed
```

**How do I remove this JavaScript code?**

Reference files:

- /libraries/joomla/html/behavior.php
- /libraries/cms/html/bootstrap.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JHtml::_('behavior.disable','behavior');` to remove specific behavior

We have so many posts on the web and forums where users are asking to remove this or
that behavior. Instead of them hacking their way trough the views and core we
could have:

JHtml::_('behavior.disable','specific behavior');  to remove the ones we don't
want

#### Example scenario

Tooltips are loaded no matter if your HTML overrides are not loading it.

`JHtml::_('behavior.disable','tooltips');` placed in template `index.php` could do
this for you and this way help you clean your head tag from unwanted scripts.

In 3.0 if you just want to remove tooltips from registration you have to copy
the view to HTML override. Remove JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip'); from the file and
then it is gone. I think that this should be done without HTML overrides.

And in 2.5.x even using HTML overrides does not help. Tooltip stays.

If any other extension that you have installed is loading behavior that you
don't want, it will take you longer to figure out where it is.

Comment: add JHtml::_('behavior.keepalive');
    JHtml::_('bootstrap.tooltip');  these block is removed.

Comment: In Joomla 3 they really need to add a good way to prevent these for people that don't want mootools...

Comment: @Cleanshooter there is. It's a plugin called mootable: https://github.com/phproberto/plg_sys_mootable ;)

Comment: In Joomla 3.4.x, `JHtml::_('behavior.disable','behavior');` does not work. I get an Error 500.

Comment: Before down voting at least check whether when the answer was posted.

Comment: Down voting could also mean it's not relevant anymore. Don't be so defensive.

Comment: It's relevant to the personals who are using Joomla! 3.0.x. Please read the question title at least correctly.

Answer (score 6):

I found a simple solution [here](http://www.acuit.com.au/Blogs/removing-jcaption-in-joomla2.5.html) and [here](https://coderwall.com/p/plp6qg):

```
unset($this->_scripts[JURI::root(true).'/media/system/js/caption.js']);
```

or

```
unset ( $this -> _metaTags[ 'http-equiv' ] ) ;
$this -> _scripts    = array ( ) ;
$this -> _script     = array ( ) ;
```

to get the whole lot. :)

**Do not use:**

```
$doc -> setHeadData($headData);
```

It does weird and mysterious things.

The problem that you (and I) were having is resetting the `$doc` variable through `$doc->setHeadData($headData)` instead of unsetting the `_scripts` and `_script` through `$this`. [Coderwall.com](https://coderwall.com/p/plp6qg) provides a thorough example.